# Accessing SharePoint Files with 3rd Party Software

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I am building a Startup to provide software solution to construction industry, and would like your input for connecting 3rd party software to Sharepoint for accessing files on SharePoint.

As part of one of the services, the software needs to access the client's SharePoint files. How can one connect a 3rd party software to SharePoint so that the users have access to files on SharePoint? What are some important things to consider? I am at the early stage of software development, and would like to start with the right foot. Your input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft already released solutions called [**Microsoft Graph Connector**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/connectors-overview)

This connector brings external data (including File shares) into SharePoint online by creating Microsoft Search index, then make it query/search/and some properties can be even refinable.

It makes as wonderful paring with PnP Modern Search webpart to bring external data content into SharePoint Online. On top of that, utilization of Microsoft Adaptive Card Designer is provided for free.